# Discord bot and bottle in the same time in Python

Tags: python, bottle, discord.py

I'm trying to do an API for a bot with bottle to use commands like `http://localhost:8080/say/serverId/channelId/Message` 
I tried successfully to print a message with url and bottle and I have a Discord bot, now I must fusion the two.
So I want to run bottle and discord in the same time, in the same script.
I searched and there is threading, ipc etc ... But theses solutions looks hard I'm a beginner. 
So do you have simple solution to do this ?
I tried

```
bot.run(token)
bottle.run(host="localhost", port=8080)
```

but the bot starts and I must stop it with `CTRL` + `C` to start bottle.
Also if you have a simpler solution but with 2 scripts why not but I need the bot variable in the bottle's script to send the message 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `bottle.py` is a WSGI framework based on blocking code, while `discord.py` is a `asyncio` asynchronous non-blocking library that uses an event loop.

Your options are:

- remove `bottle` in favor of some other web framework that is actually asynchronous (for example, [`grole`](https://github.com/witchard/grole) or [`sanic`](https://github.com/huge-success/sanic)).
- Use some wrapper like [`aiobottle`](https://github.com/Lupino/aiobottle) to somehow make bottle play nice with asyncio (or make your own).

I would go with the first option.

After using some compatible framework or wrapper, you should start the event loop only once, as it will serve for both applications. That means you can't call both `run` methods.

Example, for sanic:

```
# `bot.run` starts the event loop, avoid it and use `bot.start` instead
bot_app = bot.start(token)
bot_task = asyncio.ensure_future(bot_app)

# create the sanic app server, but without starting it:
webserver = app.create_server(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
webserver_task = asyncio.ensure_future(webserver)

#finally, start the event loop:
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_forever() # runs both tasks at the same time
```

Comment: I'll see grole and sanic but bottle is so simple :/
The two option looks cool

Comment: Now I have the same problem with Sanic

Comment: @user211593 I added how to solve the problem with sanic to the answer