# Expose discord bot to API (Flask, FASTAPI)

Tags: python, discord.py, fastapi

I'm building a discord bot to take commands from multiple systems and programs. I'm wanting to expose certain actions of my discord bot to REST endpoints and then execute said actions in one spot.

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional
from discord.ext import commands

app = FastAPI()

TOKEN = 'MY_TOKEN'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    price: float
    tax: Optional[float] = None

@app.get("/")
def hello():
    return {"message":"Hello"}

@app.post("/items/")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    await send_message()
    return item

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')

async def send_message():
    user = await bot.fetch_user(USER_ID)
    await user.send('')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.run('BOT_TOKEN')
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

When I try to run this, I'm only seeing the bot active. I'm a little newer to python but a veteran programmer. Is this due to python's "lack" of multithreading? Or port usage?

The end goal is to call the "/items/" endpoint and see a message on discord sent to me

**EDIT**

I tried all the answers and coming up with some of my own. The problem is multi-threading. I got frustrated with it and ended up just moving this piece to Node.js. It doesn't technically fulfill this question but was far easier than navigating python multithreading.

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

app.get('/listUsers', function (req, res) {

    dm_user();

    res.send('hello');
})

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('pong');
  }
});

async function dm_user(id){
    var my_user = await client.users.fetch('USER_ID');
    console.log(my_user);
}

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
   client.login('TOKEN');
})
```

Comment: So, navigating with the browser to `localhost:8000/docs` (or whatever IP address you assigned to your machine), does not return anything, right?

Comment: @isabi that is correct

Comment: when you run `bot.run('BOT_TOKEN')` then it runs this function until you stop bot and  `uvicorn.run()` is executed after closing bot. So `uvicorn.run()` is not executed and you can't connect to web page. You have to start bot in separated thread.

Answer (score 4):

According to the discord.py docs [bot.run()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.run) is "A blocking call that abstracts away the event loop initialisation from you." and further they said if we want more control over the loop we could use start() coroutine instead of run(). So now we should create a task for calling this coroutine and we know [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) all are [asynchronous](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) applications. For starting a FastAPI app you need an ASGI server to handle it. In this case, we're using [Uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/). So far we have run FastAPI app, now we need to start our discord bot. According to FastAPI docs we could use [startup/shutdown event](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/), for calling bot.start() coroutine before the main API starts.

Here is an example of an app which has an API endpoint for sending a message to a discord's user:

```
import asyncio
import discord
import uvicorn

from config import TOKEN, USER_ID
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
bot = discord.Client()

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event(): #this fucntion will run before the main API starts
    asyncio.create_task(bot.start(TOKEN))
    await asyncio.sleep(4) #optional sleep for established connection with discord
    print(f"{bot.user} has connected to Discord!")

@app.get("/")
async def root(msg: str): #API endpoint for sending a message to a discord's user
    user = await send_message(msg)
    return {"Message": f"'{msg}' sent to {user}"}

async def send_message(message):
    user = await bot.fetch_user(USER_ID)
    await user.send(message)
    return user #for optional log in the response of endpoint

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=5000)
```

Tested with Python 3.7.4

Comment: Giving upvote because this works only in the case that you're not using cogs/extensions. If the whole bot is a single file, then it works. However, if you have cogs/extensions, only the main cog will work, the others won't be executed at all.

Comment: This still works, with the new version you need to add intents to the `discord.Client(intents=intents)`

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from your `send_message` function. Something like this should do good.

```py
@app.post("/items/")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    msg = await send_message()
    return msg


async def send_message():
    user = await bot.fetch_user(USER_ID)
    return await user.send('')
```

Comment: not sure if you tried this solution. I tried it on mine and didn't come close to working. Please post the full codeset you got working for me to accept

Answer (score 0):

Code `bot.run(...)` runs all time and it blocks next line which starts API. You would have to run one of them in separated thread or process.

I tried to run `bot` in `thread`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import threading 

    print('Starting bot')
    t = threading.Thread(target=bot.start, args=(TOKEN,))
    t.start()
    
    print('Starting API')
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

but it gives me message that `bot` should run in main thread.

But I found question [Discord bot and bottle in the same time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52410570/discord-bot-and-bottle-in-the-same-time-in-python) and base on it I create code which works for me

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import asyncio
    
    print('Starting bot')
    bot_app = bot.start(TOKEN)
    bot_task = asyncio.ensure_future(bot_app)
    
    print('Starting API')
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

But I'm not sure if this is ellegant method because `uvicorn` runs `ayncio` indirectly.

---

Full version

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional
from discord.ext import commands

app = FastAPI()

#import os
#TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
TOKEN = 'MY_TOKEN'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    price: float
    tax: Optional[float] = None

@app.get("/")
def hello():
    return {"message":"Hello"}

@app.post("/items/")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    await send_message()
    return item

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')

async def send_message():
    user = await bot.fetch_user(USER_ID)
    await user.send('')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import asyncio
        
    print('Starting bot')
    bot_app = bot.start(TOKEN)
    bot_task = asyncio.ensure_future(bot_app)
        
    print('Starting API')
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: I think you're close. I tried your snippets and couldn't get it to work. could you edit your response with the full codeset just so I know I'm using the same thing?

Comment: rest it exaclty the same but I put full code.

Comment: This doesn't work because uvicorn runs it's own app forever (or until completion, which never happens unless killed, interrupted, or exits by itself). So ensure_future() will never execute.

Comment: @Fanatique do you have problem with my code or with your own code? My code works for me. It needs to use `ensure_future(bot_app)` instead of `bot.run()` and it has to do it before `uvicorn.run()`. If you have problem with your own code then better create new question on new page and you will have more space to show your code with description. Maybe your code may need totally different solution.

Comment: @furas Your code does not work. Try it yourself. When a bot is ready it should receive the `on_ready()` event, you've coded that. Do you get the `print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')` anywhere in your console? I've just stated the reason why it doesn't work. `ensure_future` doesn't run the bot before the API. It doesn't matter even if it did. If it ran before the API: the API wouldn't work. If it ran after the API: the bot will never work. Both the bot and API have blocking event loops that are separate, only one of them will work. In your example only the API is working.